# jquery disable the button when one fields text is removed?

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have two input text fields and a submit button  in a form like this

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
<input type="submit" id="submit />
```

Now I want that when both the input fields are entered with some values then the submit button will work otherwise it will be in disable mode. So for that I made my jQuery code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('submit').prop("disabled",true);
    jQuery("#name, #email").on('keyup',function() {
      var namevalue = jQuery('#name').val().length;
      var emailvalue = jQuery('#email').val().length;
      if(namevalue > 0 && emailvalue > 0) {
        jQuery('#submit').removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Now this one is working with some extend for first time. If someone has entered some text in both fields and as per code the submit button is activated now. Lets say someone has removed text from any one field or both fields by using delete or backspace button then still the button is in active mode. I want that if someone has made completely removed text from any fields or both these fields then the button should be in disable mode. So can some one tell me how to do this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: add an else part with jQuery('#submit').attr("disabled","disabled"); should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `disabled` button on else block

```
  if(namevalue > 0 && emailvalue > 0) {
    jQuery('#submit').removeAttr("disabled");
  }else{
     jQuery('#submit').prop("disabled", true);
  }
```

Above statement can be simplified using

```
  jQuery('#submit').prop("disabled", !(namevalue > 0 && emailvalue > 0));
```

Additionally in your code `jQuery('submit').prop("disabled",true);` you have missed `#`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `else` in the `if` condition:

```
  if(namevalue > 0 && emailvalue > 0) {
    jQuery('[type="submit"]').prop("disabled",false);
  }else{
   jQuery('[type="submit"]').prop("disabled",true);
  }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjPtA/)

Answer (score 0):

Note: There is a missing double quotes at your HTML mark up

Your Code: `<input type="submit" id="submit />`

Correct It: `<input type="submit" id="submit" />`

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/bkNxH/

```
$("#name, #email").keyup(function() {

    var name = $.trim($("#name").val());
    var email = $.trim($("#email").val());

    if(name != '' && email != '') {
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

});
```